# Is 貝獣 an actual pun?

Tags: kanji, puns

貝獣

Does this work out of context? Do these kanji even go together? Would it need furigana to make the pun apparent? Does it have any unfortunate implications?

Comment: Um, am I missing something?   A pun of what, 怪獣?  I would have no problem reading it as 「かいじゅう」, but I don't understand the pun-ness.  Can you explain this a little more?

Answer (score 9):

It should work as a pun for most native speakers (though not many would think it was funny).  They would not have any problems reading 「貝獣」 as 「かいじゅう」 even though it is a kun-on combo and they would think it was a shell-related monster.

I myself was one of those native speakers described above until I googled upon reading this question today to find out there is already a game named [貝獣物語{かいじゅうものがたり}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaij%C5%AB_Monogatari).

Thus, for those familiar with the game, 「貝獣」 might not work as a pun as they are accustomed to seeing the name.

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks for such a quick reply! 
It's actually supposed to be a sort of goofy name for a giant isopod kaiju monster thing, so, I guess it roughly works for an inside joke at least.
I didn't know about that game, but it looks interesting too. I'm very, very beginner level in Japanese, so I don't understand much, but thank you again for your time!